# Pandas Read Excel Read Second Tab Ignoring the Sheet Name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a python script to process multiple excel, and I want to take only second sheet on the excel file ignoring the sheet name as the name will not be the same every time.

```
try1 = pd.ExcelFile('File Path')
try1.sheet_names


Out[41]:
['Analysis Header', 'Total Individuals (4543)']
```

as you can see the Total individual will change time to time with a random number.

Thank You
Best Regards
Railey Shahril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.ExcelFile` has a method `.parse()` which works exactly like `pd.read_excel()`. Both functions accept the parameter `sheet_name` which handles many ways of selecting one or more sheets to import. In your case, you want to refer to the sheet number, so you should pass `sheet_name` an integer value indicating the sheet. Pandas numbers the sheets starting with 0, so the 2nd sheet can be selected with `sheet_name=1` as:

`pd.ExcelFile('File Path').parse(sheet_name=1)`

This is equivalent to:

`pd.read_excel('File Path', sheet_name=1)`

Th `sheet_name` and the other parameters for reading Excel files are described in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.read_excel option!

```
pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=1)
```

"sheet_name" can be sheet_name or sheet_index or list of them mixed up. The code above always take second sheet of workbook as a dataframe which solves your problem no matter what the name of your sheet is!

Take a look in this [official pandas.read_excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for more information!

Hope this helps!